# How to do continuous animation in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I want my image buttons to start from top of the screen and reach end of screen followed by another image button behind it and this goes on forever like white strips on a road. As one button reaches end of screen the portion which is not visible must be visible at the top of the screen and this should be applicable for each button.

See the image for the last image button for clear view.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgr9R.png)

This is the code for my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.ash432.itguesses.options"
android:background="#040404">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:background="#f9f6f6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_anim"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im2"
    android:background="#f9f6f6"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im3"
    android:background="#f9f6f6"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im4"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im5"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im4" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im6"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im5" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im7"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im6" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/im8"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/im7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/im7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im7" />
```

And here is the java code

```
public class options extends AppCompatActivity
{
private ImageButton im1,im2,im3,im4,im5,im6,im7,im8;
private Animation mAnimation;
//private Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);


    im1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im1);
    im2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im2);
    im3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im3);
    im4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im4);
    im5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im5);
    im6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im6);
    im7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im7);
    im8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im8);

    mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mAnimation.getStartTime();
    im1.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im2.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im3.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im4.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im5.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im6.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im7.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    im8.setAnimation(mAnimation);
}
}
```

**UPDATE-**

**For those who cannot understand the question properly.**

1)At first I want nothing on the screen just the background.

2)Then after sometime a white strip should be seen coming from top of the screen.

3)Then when it has fully come, after some time second white strip should be seen coming.

4)Same procedure for all the **Eight Image Buttons**.

5)Now when the first image button reaches the bottom of the screen . Its size should be decreasing while at the top of the screen its size should be increasing.**Similarly for all the buttons when they reach the bottom of the screen**

6)The gap between the strips should be **constant**.

Here is the image showing the steps-

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s0Tb.png)

I hope I have made my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I assume you want to recycle those white stripes.

You should use RecyclerView for this.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.ash432.itguesses.options"
android:background="#040404">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create another xml layout for those stripes and connect them using an `Adapter`.

Edit:

`RecyclerView` is an advanced version of `ListView` with better performance.It's a view, previously used to display data for a specific adapter position may be placed in a cache for **later reuse to display the same type of data again** later.

`Adapter` is a subclass of RecyclerView.Adapter responsible for providing views that represent items in a data set.

[here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) is a great source that you can learn how to implement recyclerview.

Comment: Actually I'm new to Android. So I dont know how to use Adapter and Recycler View.Could you please elaborate in detail ??

Comment: I had difficulty in implementing the Adapter and Recycler View. Also my Android Studio is not supporting Recycler View . Could you suggest any other way to do this?? Also read my UPDATE if you havnt understand my question.